Hydrogen adsorption on 2D materials storage
I do hydrogen storage on 2D materials by adsorption on material composed only by carbon.
First of all, I have started by generating QE input file from Material Project site web. Then I relaxed them through vc-relax calculations to find relaxed cell parameters and atomic positions from the output file. After putting this relaxed parameters into input file and start self-consistent-field calculation, we find out the total energy of pristine structure called Etot(Pristine). In this stage we start putting the hydrogen molecules on the surface, I start by one hydrogen molecule at defined position. And I start again vc-relax of all of system, to find out its total energy after scf calculation with relaxed parameters from relaxed output file, this energy noted E(pristine + 1H2).
Now I am looking to calculate the adsorption energy. Formulated as Eads = Etot(pristine+1H2) - Etot(pristine) - E(H2). I don't know wich energies I'll take for E(pristine) and E(H2)??? Some help please!!!!!

+1. Welcome to our community!

Take a look here and here. Also, if you search the forum for "binding energy" will find other related post about calculating binding/adsorption energy.
